# Pug error in counter

Tags: javascript, html, pug

because there is an error in this syntax, I do not know how to make the variable count without having to do inside an tag:

```
html
    head
        link(href="ok.css")
    body
        - var i = 0
        - var max_li = 10
        ul
            while i < max_li
                i++ // <- error
                li
```

In [this documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html#while) the counter does it with the `LI` label but I want to do it without having to assign this from an `LI`. Someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or how I could do it..

Comment: you can assign a class for the li tags and getElementsByClassName this will return an array and you should be able to get the length of those li you would like to be counted.

Comment: Perhaps `while i < max_li { 
               li
                i++ }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `- i++`

Example:

```
- var i = 0
- var max_li = 10
ul
  while i < max_li
    - i++ 
    li= i
```